# keeping audio in sync when they want to make more video edits

Tags: pro-tools, sync, conform, re-conforming

I just finished my first 22 minute webisode the director and producer are both happy with the sound design but want to tighten up some of the video edits. I don't know what to do in this situation since any change that is made is going to set audio off sync in pro tools. Is there anything in particular that you guys do during such situations.

Thanks 
~reN

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!  I recommend running a search on here for 'conform' and you'll actually find a MOUNTAIN of valuable information on this.  'Conform' or 're-conform' are the actual terms for what you speak of, so hopefully that helps.